# What is the reason that a java method cannot return more than one value?

Tags: java, python

As you know in python, a function can returns more than one value

eg:

```
def myfun():
    return 1, 2, 3
```

And we can call it in this way:

```
a, b, c= myfun()
```

But in JAVA, we have cannot return more that one value, so we have to create one object containing the values that we want to return:

```
class MyObject {

    private Integer a;
    private Integer b;
    private Integer c;

    public Integer getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(Integer a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public Integer getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(Integer b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public Integer getC() {
        return c;
    }
    public void setC(Integer c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

and our function will return this object

eg:

```
public MyObject myfun(){
     MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
     myObject.setA(1);
     myObject.setB(2);
     myObject.setC(3);
     return myObject;
}
```

ِAnd we call it in this way:

```
obj = myfun();
Integer a = obj.getA();
Integer b = obj.getB();
Integer c = obj.getC();
```

Another solution is to return an array containing all the values that should be returned

But the both methods are ugly in coding, is there any limitation in JAVA so a method cannot returns more than one value?

Comment: as `java` is an OOP language it makes enough sense to create a `class` if all these value are connected. i Don´t see the `ugly` part there.

Comment: Java is not Python.  Yes, there's a limitation.  It's been that way since the language was designed in 1995.

Comment: Java is deliberately designed to look like C.  In C this is the way it works.

Comment: As a matter of fact, in Python you also always return one value, in your case a tuple containing 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strictly speaking, Python does not return more than one value either. `1, 2, 3` is a tuple; it's just that Python's syntax supports automatically unpacking that tuple into separate variables.

Answer (score 8):

That Python function is only returning one value.

```
>>> def myfun():
...     return 1, 2, 3
...
>>> a = myfun()
>>> type(a)
<class 'tuple'>
```

As you can see, it's a container, just like you need in Java.